# Any way to do this in any text editor?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I have a file which is like

```
email = myemail@gmail.com
email = myemail@gmail.com
email = myemail@gmail.com
```

Can I make it like this?

```
email = myemail1@gmail.com
email = myemail2@gmail.com
email = myemail3@gmail.com
```

Can I do this in any text editor? Or is there any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/about.php), but for Notepad++:

> hold Alt and select the column of numbers that you wish to change.
>   Then go to Edit->Column Editor and select the Number to Insert radio
>   button in the window that appears. Then specify your initial number
>   and increment, and hit OK. It should write out the incremented
>   numbers.

copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace).

To apply it, do it once for `@gmail.com` then the `1,2,3`, lastly the prefix `email = myemail`.

I really like to recommend vim (again), you could do many stuff like these with one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

Whack it into excel and write a formula to insert the row number before the @ symbol.
=Substitute(YourCell, "@", Row() & "@")

EDIT:

Assuming that you have your email in cell A1, the formula would be

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@",ROW()&"@")
```

Comment: im getting a weird form in excel.. any other way?

Comment: a weird form? You should not get any form. What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

SlickEdit can do with a block-selection and then an enumeration insertion.

Basically, select a vertical block before the "@", 3 lines high.

Then insert an enumeration starting at 1.