# Notepad++ Copy/paste with one change

Tags: python, sublimetext2, notepad++

```
<contact>
                <buddy account='19999999999' proto='prpl-whatsapp'>
                    <name>979999999999</name>
            </contact>
```

The above text , I want to copy and paste below each other 100 times with one change in the text

This part - `<name>979999999999</name>`

How can do this in notepad++ , python , sublime text?

Comment: I think it could be done with column editor - as seen in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602876/3365805

Comment: Tried but it just adding a line with an increment in the number

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in that line?

Comment: Not in that line , I want to add more similar lines like <name>979999999991</name>
<name>979999999992</name>
<name>979999999993</name>
<name>979999999994</name>
<name>979999999995</name>
<name>979999999996</name>
<name>979999999997</name>
<name>979999999998</name>
<name>979999999999</name>  you see with incrementing number. I want to ADD 1000 lines lets say , how can we do it

Answer (score 0):

In **SynWrite** app you can do it: call dialog "Edit - Insert text", enter:

- prefix: `<name>`
- start number 979999999991
- suffix: `</name>`
- counter: 100