# Notepad++ change text with auto increment

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, notepad++

i have database sql file. i was change all user name with "000000000"  and i want to replace it with notepad++ like this

"school0001"

"school0002"

"school0003"

"school0004"

This is original sql codes

```
(16, 2, '', 0, '000000000', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', '9oV', '2014-12-30', 'homeros61@hotmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
(17, 2, '', 0, '000000000', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', 'ZP\\', '2014-12-30', 'boraimer34@hotmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
(18, 2, '', 0, '000000000', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', 'jde', '2014-12-30', 'ozgureoner@gmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
(19, 2, '', 0, '000000000', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', 'drQ', '2014-12-30', 'muzo-0511@hotmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
```

i want like this

```
(16, 2, '', 0, 'school0001', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', '9oV', '2014-12-30', 'homeros61@hotmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
(17, 2, '', 0, 'school0002', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', 'ZP\\', '2014-12-30', 'boraimer34@hotmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
(18, 2, '', 0, 'school0003', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', 'jde', '2014-12-30', 'ozgureoner@gmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
(19, 2, '', 0, 'school0004', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'legacy', 'drQ', '2014-12-30', 'muzo-0511@hotmail.com', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0, 2, '', 0, 1419950423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67127382, NULL, 134217722, '', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, '', 'vb', '', 0, NULL, 0),
```

Comment: That's not a job for editor+regex. You'd better write a script in your favorite language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++ incrementally replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace)

Comment: some web site says use \i regex but it not work. i hope someone can help

Comment: thanks to all. i found how to replace. download textpad and replace all 0000000 with \i :)))

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. If you want to improve this Q/A, please transform that comment into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

i want to share my answer.

Download textpad and replace all 0000000 with \i

if you want you can do like this to.

```
Searching text: 0000000
Replace with: school\i
```

Output: school1, school2, school3, school4, school5 and how much you have same text...

And also

```
\i Replace with numbers starting from 1, incrementing by 1. 
\i(10) Replace with numbers starting from 10, incrementing by 1. 
\i(0,10) Replace with numbers starting from 0, incrementing by 10. 
\i(100,-10) Replace with numbers starting from 100, decrementing by -10.
```

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite app.

- Install "Carets numbering" plugin in Addons manager
- Place multi-carets on all words, using Ctrl+Shift+click (see help).
- Call "Tools/ plugins/ carets numbering"