# Is there a way to use regex to replace the same value multiple times, but with each subsequent replacement, replace the original value with a new one?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Let's say the value I want to replace is "x", and I have "x" on multiple lines

So, for example:

```
ax
ex
ix
ox
ux
```

and say I have a list of different values ( using numbers 1-5 in place of replacement values for the sake of example )
 I want to replace "x" with. Now, typical replacement only allows you to replace "x" with a single value.

( In this example, "x" is replaced with "1" )

```
a1
e1
i1
o1
u1
```

What I'm trying to figure out is there's a way to change the value that replaces the original value each subsequent time "x" is replaced. So, instead of only being able to replace each "x" with "1" each time, "x" is replaced with "1" the first time "x" is replaced, and then the second time "x" is replaced with "2", next time "x" is replaced with "3" and so on.

```
a1
e2
i3
o4
u5
```

I'm using Notepad++ btw.

Comment: so, regex on what programming language..?

Comment: @BagusTesa My apologies, I forgot to mention I was using Notepad++. Just added to my inquiry

Comment: Do you need a function (may be in JS or some other language) to do so or you want all functionality in regular expression only?

Comment: No. Regular expressions don't do math.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602876/4392605) ? Try to learn Vim which is powerful in such cases